# Determining how cocoapods was installed

Tags: cocoapods

**Background**

A few years ago I installed cocoapods for a project I was working on. Since then I have not used it and now I need to update it to get Flutter working.

**System**

- OS MacOS Mojave
- Version 10.14.3

**Question**

I do not want to end up installing 2 different versions of cocoapods and cause myself a bunch of problems. I am trying to determine how I originally installed cocoapods so I can update it.

How can I determine how cocoapods was originally installed?

**What I Tried**

I can see cocoapods is installed because when I run,

`pod --version` the output is

> 1.3.1

When I run `which cocoapods` I get

> cocoapods not found

When I run `which pod` I get

> /usr/local/bin/pod

I checked that file and it is a cocoapods file installed by a ruby gem. This is what I see when I look at the file,

> ## !/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
>
> #
>
> ## This file was generated by RubyGems.
>
> #
>
> ## The application 'cocoapods' is installed as part of a gem, and
>
> ## this file is here to facilitate running it.

At this point I try and update it,

```
gem update cocoapods
```

I get,

> Updating installed gems Nothing to update

When I run `gem list` I get a list of installed gems but `pods` nor `cocoapods` is in the list.

I also checked `brew list` and do not see it installed in there either. I can see evidence that it was installed as a gem but I do not understand why `gem update cocoapods` finds nothing to update.

**Update**

I broke down and went ahead and tried to install cocoapods as a gem since I already had the gem file in place.

```
gem install cocoapods
```

When I run `gem list` it shows that cocoapods was installed as version 1.6.1 as there are a bunch of new cocoapods files in my gem list.

When I run `pod --version` it still says 1.3.1.

I removed the pod file from `/usr/local/bin` and then ran pod --version again. At this point I get a `command not found` error.

After adding it back I can see the same output of the old version exists again. 1.3.1.

I tried removing the old pod file from `/usr/local/bin` and then `gem install cocoapods`. After doing so the pod command will not work but I can see that cocoapods is installed as a gem on my system.

Answer (score 4):

Evidently there is a problem installing cocoapods on some newer MacOS systems due to the all of the permissions changes rolled out from Apple.

I saw a suggestion to install cocoapods on El Captain like this,

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Which would explain why I have a rogue pod file inside of that directory.

**Solution**

- I deleted the pod file out of my `/usr/local/bin` folder.
- I installed cocoapods again using => `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Now when I run `pod --version` I get 1.6.1.